# Create alert using materialize css

Tags: materialize

I want to create an alert using materialize css. I don't know how. Please help. I just want to create a simple html that will display an alert error without using javascript. Thanks.

Comment: what kind of alert ?

Comment: Simple alert box just like bootstrap.

Comment: read docs at `http://materializecss.com/dialogs.html`

Comment: The docs has less info. I want to load it automatically without using buttons. Is that possible?

Comment: Where do i put onload?

Comment: forget onload ... check your answer below?

Answer (score 12):

since this has no answer yet, I made something that may help you. [Here is the repo](https://github.com/SimiAPM/materialert)

And here is a preview.

```css
html {
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,Oxygen-Sans,Ubuntu,Cantarell,"Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;
}
.materialert{
    position: relative;
    min-width: 150px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    transition: all 0.1s linear;
    webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.materialert .material-icons{
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.materialert .close-alert{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: inherit;
    background: 0 0;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    right: 5px;
}
.materialert.info{
    background-color: #039be5;
    color: #fff;
}
.materialert.success{
    background-color: #43a047;
    color: #fff;
}
.materialert.error{
    background-color: #c62828;
    color: #fff;
}
.materialert.danger{
    background-color: #c62828;
    color: #fff;
}
.materialert.warning{
    background-color: #fbc02d;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<html lang="es-MX">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="css/materialert.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
 <body>
  <div class="materialert">
      <i class="material-icons">check_circle</i> <span>Bienvenido, Linebeck</span>
      <button type="button" class="close-alert">×</button>
  </div>
  <div class="materialert info">
      <div class="material-icons">info_outline</div>
      Oh! What a beautiful alert :)
  </div>
  <div class="materialert error">
      <div class="material-icons">error_outline</div>
      Oh! What a beautiful alert :)
  </div>
  <div class="materialert success">
      <div class="material-icons">check</div>
      Oh! What a beautiful alert :)
  </div>
  <div class="materialert warning">
      <div class="material-icons">warning</div>
      Oh! What a beautiful alert :)
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 10):

Materializecss alert box
 [Codepen link](http://codepen.io/pradeep1616/pen/LxaRRB)

```
<div class="row" id="alert_box">
 <div class="col s12 m12">
  <div class="card red darken-1">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m10">
      <div class="card-content white-text">
        <p>1. Username cant be empty</p>
        <p>2. Password cant be empty</p>
        <p>3. Address cant be empty</p>
        <p>4. Name cant be empty</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col s12 m2">
    <i class="fa fa-times icon_style"                             id="alert_close" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

.icon_style{
position: absolute;
right: 10px;
top: 10px;
font-size: 20px;
color: white;
cursor:pointer; 
}

$('#alert_close').click(function(){
$( "#alert_box" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
});
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately materialize doesn't provide alerts as bootstrap does.
You can use `card-panel` class instead:

http://materializecss.com/color.html

But you won't have close button to hide it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty late answer but you can use the `modal` class for these kind of things.

**Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    // the "href" attribute of .modal-trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
    $('.modal').modal();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <!-- Modal Trigger -->
  <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" href="#modal1">Modal</a>

  <!-- Modal Structure -->
  <div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Alert</h4>
      <p>You can use this as a alert!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">OK</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Reference:** http://materializecss.com/modals.html#!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14912796)

Comment: I will add something straight away.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   Materialize.toast('I am Alert', 4000)

});
```

**See** **DEMO** *here*: http://codepen.io/ihemant360/pen/pbPyJb

Answer (score 1):

You can use Matdialog.js to create different types of dialogboxes.

check it out at - [MatDialog.js website](https://ujjwalguptaofficial.github.io/MatDialog/)

Answer (score 1):

## Install Toastr

`bower install toastr`

## Require files

- `/bower_components/toastr.css`
- `/bower_components/toastr.js`

## initialize toastr

`toastr.options = {
    "closeButton": true,
    "debug": false,
    "newestOnTop": false,
    "progressBar": false,
    "positionClass": "toast-bottom-left",
    "preventDuplicates": true,
    "onclick": null,
    "showDuration": "300",
    "hideDuration": "1000",
    "timeOut": "3000",
    "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
    "showEasing": "swing",
    "hideEasing": "linear",
    "showMethod": "fadeIn",
    "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
  }`

## Use

- Success: `toastr.success('success');`
- Error: `toastr.error('fail');`
- Info:  `toastr.info('info');`

## Credit

- Documentation: https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr
- Demo: http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by using chips (https://materializecss.com/chips.html) and formating css style to fit the purpose.

https://codepen.io/krazer_spa/pen/VRmxzy

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="flash_message">
            <div class="chip chip_message_info">
                This is an info message
                <i class="close material-icons">close</i>
            </div>
            <div class="chip chip_message_warning">
                This is a warning message
                <i class="close material-icons">close</i>
            </div>
            <div class="chip chip_message_alert">
                This is an alert message
                <i class="close material-icons">close</i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <style>

    .flash_message {
        position: fixed;
        top: 70px;
        z-index: 99999;
        min-width: 80%;
    }

    .chip_message_info,
    .chip_message_warning,
    .chip_message_alert {
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 10px !important;
        padding-bottom: 10px !important;
        font-size: 20px !important;
        min-width: 80%;
        min-height: 50px;
    }

    .chip_message_info {
        background-color: #bbdefb !important;
    }

    .chip_message_warning {
        background-color: #ffcc80 !important;
    }

    .chip_message_alert {
        background-color: #ef9a9a !important;
    }

    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

ReactJS + Materialize

**Alert.js**

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Alert = ({ type, children }) => {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(true);

  // set alert color based on type
  let color;
  switch (type) {
    case "danger":
      color = "red lighten-2";
      break;
    case "success":
      color = "green lighten-2";
      break;
    case "info":
      color = "blue lighten-2";
      break;
    case "warning":
      color = "yellow lighten-2";
      break;
    default:
      color = "white lighten-2";
      break;
  }
  return (
    <>
      {isVisible && (
        <div className="row mv--small" id="alert-box">
          <div className="col s12 m12">
            <div className={`card m--none z-depth-0 ${color}`}>
              <div className="card-content black-text">{children}</div>
              <i
                className="material-icons icon_style"
                id="alert_close"
                aria-hidden="true"
                onClick={() => setIsVisible(false)}
              >
                close
              </i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Alert;
```

You can then use it like this:

```
<Alert type="info">
test
</Alert>
```

And it looks like this:

[image]